# PHP Group sql query under the same title

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a restaurant site where the people can see the menu.

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

And now I want to output this data according the title:

**Pizza**

Ham & Cheese $150

Onion & Cheese $120

**Salad**

Caesar $70

Tomate & Olives $60

**Dessert**

Icecream $110

Vanilla Cake $90

-

Well at the future the menu_title can be changed by the client... That means the title need to be retrieved also from the database.

Here is the code I am trying but I don't have idea how to add the content below the title:

```
<?PHP
    $sql_product="SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants_menu WHERE menu_asoc='$asoc' AND menu_type='product' GROUP BY menu_title";
    $stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);
    $stmt_product->execute();           
    $result_product = $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($result_product > 0) {
        while($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
            echo '<h3>'. $row['menu_title'] .'</h3><br><p>'. $row['menu_product'] .'</p>';
        }
    }

?>
```

But this code only output the title and the first row :S

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I got 2 answer correct:

OPTION 1

```
$sql_product="SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants_menu WHERE menu_asoc='$asoc' AND menu_type='product'";
$stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);
$stmt_product->execute();           
$result_product = $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result_product > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
        $menuArr[$row['menu_title']][] = '<p>'. $row['menu_product'] . ''. $row['menu_product_price'] . ''. $row['menu_product_desc'] .'</p>';
    }

    foreach($menuArr as $menuTitle => $productArr){
        echo '<h3>'. $menuTitle .'</h3></br>';
        foreach($productArr as $key =>$productname){
        echo '<p>'. $productname .'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

OPTION 2

```
$sql_product="SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants_menu WHERE menu_asoc='$asoc' AND menu_type='product' ORDER BY menu_title";
$stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);
$stmt_product->execute();           
$result_product = $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$title = "";
while ($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
    if ($row['menu_title'] != $title) {
        echo '<h3>'.$row['menu_title'].'</h3><br>';
        $title = $row['menu_title'];
    }
    echo '<p>'.$row['menu_product'].'</p><p>'.$row['menu_product_price'].'</p>';                        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
$sql_product="SELECT * FROM cc_restaurants_menu WHERE menu_asoc='$asoc' AND menu_type='product'";
$stmt_product = $conn->prepare($sql_product);
$stmt_product->execute();           
$result_product = $stmt_product->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($result_product > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
        $menuArr[$row['menu_title']][] = $row['menu_product'] . " ".$row['menu_price'];

    }

    foreach($menuArr as $menuTitle => $productArr){
        echo '<h3>'. $menuTitle .'</h3>';
        foreach($productArr as $key =>$productname){
        echo '<p>'. $productname .'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working perfect!! Still don't understand well how I can add my html and the other variables I had but is really useful

Comment: Why are you writing `</br>`? I see that so often lately! Where does this come from? Why do you think this is correct?

Comment: @dhi_m That doesn't answer my question. I want to know where the sudden influx of `</br>`s come from. It only started last week or so. There must be a source! Some textbook or something which has a typo! I need to know what it is and eradicate the issue at the source!

Comment: @Mr Lister its by mistake

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer doing this:
Just `SELECT * ... ORDER BY menu_title`, and then sort it in PHP:

```
$title = "";
while ($row = $stmt_product->fetch()) {
  if ($row['menu_title'] != $title)
    echo '<h3>'.$row['menu_title'].'</h3><br>';
  $title = $row['menu_title'];
  echo '<p>'.$row['menu_product'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to change `GROUP BY` to `ORDER BY`

Comment: If you have your code working, could you put one answer as the correct answer or add your answer as the correct answer, so the next person having the same problem can know which answer to look please ?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` will return 1 row for each unique value - which is why you are only seeing 1 row.

**Option 1**

Use this query to output the 'Menu Title' only, passing the Menu Title to a second query inside the loop, to return rows matching the Menu Title.

**Option 2**

Remove the `GROUP BY` in your query, loop through the results using 'logic' to only output the menu Title if it is different from the previous Menu Title.