# how to sort post titles under their correct category names PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched for about 4 hours today on how to do this.
I want to pull all post titles and categories from the posts table and 
essentially want to list the "Funny" category and then list all post that have the funny category under that category. Right now I am getting the following:
Funny
   -post title
Funny
   -post title
I want to output 
Funny
   -post title
   -post title

```
    <?php
$query = "SELECT post_category,post_title FROM posts ";
$select_categories_sidebars = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
?>
<h4>Blog Categories</h4>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<ul class="list-group">
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_sidebars)) {
$post_title = $row['post_title'];
$post_tags = $row['post_category'];
echo "<li class='list-group-item'>$post_tags</li><ul>";
echo "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='category.php?category=$post_title'> {$post_title}</a></li></ul>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're going to want your query to look like this I think. `$query = "SELECT post_category,post_title FROM posts GROUP BY post_category ";` -- Look into Group By with Mysql I think that will acheive what you want.

Comment: This seemed to improve it, although it only echoed one post under each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I basically got it working how I want I just need to format it correctly now, but it is working with some help from this question. [PHP Group sql query under the same title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863003/php-group-sql-query-under-the-same-title?rq=1)

```
<?php

            $query = "SELECT post_category,post_title FROM posts ORDER BY post_tags";
            $select_categories_sidebars = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            ?>


            <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php
                        $title = "";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_categories_sidebars)) {
                            if ($row['post_category'] != $title) {
                                echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$row['post_category'].'</li><br>';
                                $title = $row['post_category'];
                            }
                            echo '<li class="list-group-item">'.$row['post_title'];
                        }

                        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do the trick:

First you should sort your query by category:

```
$query = "SELECT post_category,post_title FROM posts ORDER BY post_category";
```

Then do this:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_sidebars)) {
   $post_title = $row['post_title'];
   $post_tags = $row['post_category'];
   $used_tag = null,
   // check if you already posted that category/tag. If not, show it:
   if($used_tag!=$post_tags) {
        echo "<li class='list-group-item'>$post_tags</li>"; // I removed a '</ul>' here
        // set this title as 'used'
        $used_tag=$post_tags;
   }
   echo "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='category.php?category=$post_title'> {$post_title}</a></li>"; // I removed a '</ul>' here too
}
?>
```

***BUT***
In an ideal world you'd have two tables to accomplish this.
One for the categories, one for the posts. Each table with id's to work with
This way you produce a lot of redundant data, it's more complicated to filter, and so on...
You might want to have a look at relational database design.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That fixed the category part, but it is still only echoing one post underneath each category. How would you do this with two tables? Two queries or same query?

Comment: have you GROUPed or ORDERed your query?

Comment: hmm well now it is ordering all of the categories in alphabetical order, but echoing a category name for every post that exists. So yes It is Ordered now.

Comment: hm.... sure you've compied my code correct? I don't see why it should echo every category... curious..

Comment: Yes I have now checked about 5 times ha.

Comment: Let me test it later what's wrong with it! I have to go offline now. But maybe I've helped to anyway with the tip!?